# Javascript transtion "jumps" instead of transitioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I am trying to transition some images across a page using javascript css and html. I have the javascript set up to add the css class name to complete the transtion. However when I load the page the image jumps instead of transitioning. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am quite stuck. Here is my code:

```js
window.onload;



var movepic1 = document.getElementById("pic1");
console.log(movepic1);

function classChange(){

movepic1.className = "trans";
    
}

console.log(movepic1);

setTimeout(classChange, 3000);
```

```css
.fold_pics{
    margin: 0 0 0 180px;
    padding-top: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    width:40%;
    position:
}
.fold_pics img{
    display: inline-block;
    
    
}
#pic1{
    position: relative;
    right: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    opacity: .3;
    
    /*transition code */
    -webkit-transition: right 3.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: right 3.0s ease;
    transition: right 3.0s ease;
        
     -webkit-transition: opacity 3.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3.0s ease;
    transition: opacity 3.0s ease;
}
#pic1.trans{
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1.0;
    
    /*transition code */
    -webkit-transition: right 3.0s;
    -moz-transition: right 3.0s;
    transition: right 3.0s
        
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3.0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3.0s;
    transition: opacity 3.0s;
    
}
#pic2{
    position: relative;
    right: 64%;
    width: 33%;
    opacity: .89;
}
#pic3{
    position: relative;
    left:20%;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="fold_pics">
                
        <img id="pic3" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Buildings%20Pic.png" alt="pic3">
            
        <img id="pic2" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Hardware%20Pic.png" alt="pic2">
            
            
        <img id="pic1" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Data%20Pic.png" alt="data_pic">
            
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just fyi, you shouldn't copy all the properties from `#pic1` into `#pic1.trans`... only those that you wish to change. Also, you should only put the transition rules in the block that effects the element _before_ it transitions.

Answer (score 2):

You've basically overridden the position transition with the opacity transition. 
 You need to comma-separate them, rather than have multiple transition attributes, like this...

```
transition: right 3.0s, opacity 3.0s;
```

Also, you don't need to put the transition attribute in both `#pic1` and `#pic1.trans` - it just needs to be in `#pic1.trans`

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the `right` transition with `opacity`.

This is how you use multiple properties:

```
transition: right 3.0s ease, opacity 3.0s ease;
```

OR just use `all` if you want them **all**:

```
transition: all 3.0s ease;
```

Running example:

```js
window.onload;



var movepic1 = document.getElementById("pic1");
console.log(movepic1);

function classChange() {

  movepic1.className = "trans";

}

console.log(movepic1);

setTimeout(classChange, 3000);
```

```css
.fold_pics {
  margin: 0 0 0 180px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  position:
}

.fold_pics img {
  display: inline-block;
}

#pic1 {
  position: relative;
  right: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
  opacity: .3;
  /*transition code */
  transition: right 3.0s ease, opacity 3.0s ease;
}

#pic1.trans {
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#pic2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 64%;
  width: 33%;
  opacity: .89;
}

#pic3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold_pics">

  <img id="pic3" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Buildings%20Pic.png" alt="pic3">

  <img id="pic2" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Hardware%20Pic.png" alt="pic2">


  <img id="pic1" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Data%20Pic.png" alt="data_pic">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. Chrome developer tools wasn't updating my code as I wrote it. By using Ctrl + F5 the code updated and works fine. Thanks to everybody who help me out with their tips. Your input has increased the organization of my code.